# Unable to click on some grayed out submit button in a webpage

Tags: vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've created a script in vba using IE to fill in few inputs in a webpage in order to populate a certain item.

Following are the steps I would like my script to perform:

1. Select `Buy Bricks` from landing page
2. Enter age (35) and country (United Kingdom) and then click on `submit` button
3. On the next page, enter the unique identification number 
   for the Lego piece in the `Element/design number` box, for example `4219725`

My script can satisfy first two requirements (except for the clicking on the submit button). The submit button is still grayed out even when the input boxes are duly filled in. Once the `submit` button is clicked, I wish to fulfill the third requirement.

[Site address](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/replacementparts)

My try:

```
Sub GetDetails()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, I As Long
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, post As Object, ageInput As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/replacementparts"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
        Html.querySelectorAll(".arrow-list-info")(2).Click

        Do: Set ageInput = Html.querySelector("input[id*='How old']"): DoEvents: Loop While ageInput Is Nothing
        ageInput.Focus
        ageInput.innerText = 30

        Do: Set post = Html.querySelector("select[ng-model='country']"): DoEvents: Loop While post Is Nothing
        For I = 0 To post.Length - 1
            If InStr(post(I).innerText, "United Kingdom") > 0 Then post(I).Selected = True: Exit For
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

***How can I activate the grayed out submit button in order to initiate click on it?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a change event to the select element

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetDetails()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument, ageInput As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/replacementparts"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set html = .document
        Dim event_onChange As Object
        Set event_onChange = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        event_onChange.initEvent "change", True, False
        html.querySelectorAll(".arrow-list-info")(2).Click

        Do: Set ageInput = html.querySelector("input[id*='How old']"): DoEvents: Loop While ageInput Is Nothing
        ageInput.innerText = 30
        html.querySelector("[label='United Kingdom").Selected = True
        IE.document.querySelector("select").dispatchEvent event_onChange
        IE.document.querySelector("[ng-click='startFlow()'").Click

        Do: Loop While IE.document.querySelectorAll("[ng-model=itemNumber]").Length = 0
        IE.document.querySelector("[ng-model=itemNumber]").Focus
        IE.document.querySelector("[ng-model=itemNumber]").Value = "4219725"
        Stop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Button seems to be alive now but the click is not being performed. I tried this `Html.querySelector("button[class*='pull-right']")`. I even manually clicked on that button but no luck.

Comment: Add a change event instead.

Comment: Yes, the click is now working perfectly. I had one last requirement (number 3) you can see in my post to be satisfied. Thanks for being with me.

Comment: Pleased to hear it. Keep the interesting questions coming.